# Star Trek episode involving an old person who was supposed to be buried alive/dying on a moon or asteroid because he reached a certain age

Tags: star-trek, episode-identification

This must be the easiest question for Trekkies … but I just can’t find it with a Google search.

They find a moon or asteroid with dead people on it, but one just arrived through a portal or a transporter and is still alive.

Comment: The question title sounds like _TNG: Half a Life_.

Comment: Episode titles go in quotation marks. And it doesn't sound much like "Half a Life."

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I believe this could be the *Star Trek: Voyager* episode, [Emanations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emanations_(Star_Trek:_Voyager)).

In it, people are transported to what they believe is the Afterlife, prior to death. However, it turns out it's just a cavern on an asteroid. Harry was in the cavern and was accidentally brought back.

Comment: A note: the dying characters in this episode had a) a terminal brain tumour and b) an injury that made them "a burden to their family". The detail about dying due to reaching a certain age might be misremembered from the Next Generation episode [Half a Life](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Half_a_Life_(episode)) instead.

Comment: It definitely was Emanations - but I only had good memories of the character Hatil who was not sick, just old and not Ptera.